# How to bold the FIRST SENTENCE in wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress

I'm not really a programmer and I tried searching on google, but without any results. Most of them show how bold the first LINE or WORD in post.

Anyone can guide me how to do it?

Comment: How do you define sentence? Until the first full stop?

Comment: Yes, until the first dot in the content.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine, and according to this post:

https://ithemes.com/tutorials/formatting-wordpress-posts/

You basically type what you want to say, highlight the text you want in Bold and click the Bold button in the toolbar at the top.